# Java File.length() return value: different in J6 vs J7?

Tags: java, file

Comparing the two docs for [Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) and [7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) I see no mention in the first one whether 0L might be returned "because of an I/O exception" (quite a broad description), as well. Additionally, if Java 6 behaves the same, I expect there would be a way to check for this distinction ([java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29)), which again seems to lack.

Does anyone have experience with this behavior under J6?

Comment: Following your link, Java 6 document did talk about `0L` return value.

Comment: Yes, it did. But in the case of 7, it specifies explicitly that 0L may be returned in the case of an "I/O exception". This seems a broader term than only the file not being found - or am I reading this wrong? Are the two cases necessarily identical? I see, however, how my initial post could be misleading.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're doing on two different systems block size will make a difference in the values being returned.

Comment: That is a very interesting observation, that, frankly, didn't cross my mind. Appreciated!

Comment: However, I am more interested in the 0L value. For example: could another process (such as an antivirus exclusive lock) make this method return that value? Will such a case fall under an "IO exception" umbrella, as J7 says, because it certainly isn't a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: You can try FileLock to check this: one thread locks the file, another tries to get its length. More complicated, 1: locks a file, 2: reads its length 1: writes to a file, 2: reads its length

Comment: Thank you, Vitaly. I did a test in the past, in another context. Looking back, I might have failed to use an exclusive lock, that's why my code didn't perform as expected. I will give it another go; although per the docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html), behavior varies with OSs...goes as far as locks actually being considered advisory. This is a pet peeve, and I am already running with very specific issues, affecting less than 1% of my user-base, that's why I'd like to cover any "hole" in my game.

Comment: Yes, so you will know how it behaves in a particular OS (or OSs) you use :)

Comment: Perhaps, doing this in the same thread but with different variables will do the same.